# Can we use combination of AWS and Google Cloud resources in a single serverless.yml file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

We are using AWS primarily for our application but we also need to use a particular Google service. This service requires us to upload media on Google Cloud Storage.
Like AWS resources, we want to use the serverless framework to create all required GCP resources.

I need your help to know the answer to the below questions:

- How can we use the same serverless.yml to create required GCP resources as well?
- Do we need to use two serverless.yml files, one for AWS and other for Google?
- How to manage credentials for creating and accessing GCP resources?

Answer (score 1):

1. How can we use the same serverless.yml to create required GCP resources as well?

Since YAML is just [(from the docs)](https://yaml.org/)

> a human friendly data serialization
>     standard for all programming languages.

there is no proper way to have one file that fits both architectures, by looking at both examples the just change a few lines,so you wont be able to use the same file but it will be very similar

2. Do we need to use two serverless.yml files, one for AWS and other for Google?

Yes both services need specific configurations for them to work correctly

3. How to manage credentials for creating and accessing GCP resources

To access GCP resources you will use [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) this is all managed by [Cloud IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts) and it's made to represent a non-human user, in this case a app, an API, service, etc.

EXTRA: Some useful links:

- [App Egine configuration with yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml)
- [AWS serveless .yml example](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/)